# How to get the name of a specific column using a column number in R

Tags: r

I have created a function which finds the mean of all the columns in a matrix.
It looks like this:

```
Finding_mean <- function(m = c(matrix)) {    
  i = 1
  while(i < 15){ 
  matrix_mean = (mean(matrix[,i],na.rm=TRUE))     
  print(matrix_mean) 
  i = i + 1
  }
  }
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
[1] 38.921
[1] 7.702
[1] 6.259
[1] 1.026
[1] 4.635
[1] 0.069
[1] 4.261
[1] 32.007
[1] 30.866
[1] 9.123916
[1] 0.4012346
[1] 24.11404
[1] 10.33333
[1] 62.873
```

Instead of just values, i want the name of the column to be printed along with the values like this:

```
white = 38.921
black = 7.702
```

etc.
I want this code that prints the name of the column to go in my while loop, therefore I need a function that prints the name of the column when I give it the matrix name and column number. I tried using

```
colnames(matrix[1, i)
```

which gives null and I know it is because row and column names cannot be called via an index, but what is the alternative?

Please help!

Comment: `colnames(matrix)[i]` would work if the matrix has column names.

Comment: `colMeans(matrix)` is good if the mean is all you want. In more generality, `apply(matrix, 2, mean)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using loop and while in R.

R Base code:

```
paste(colnames(mat), apply(mat, 2, mean, na.rm = T), sep = " = ")
```

Used following code to create matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(data = rnorm(100, 10), ncol = 10)
colnames(mat) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works using a dataframe:

```
cars <- mtcars
cmeans <- colMeans(cars)
outputs <- paste0(colnames(cars), ' = ', cmeans)
df <- data.frame(outputs)
df$outputs <- format(df$outputs, justify = 'left')
head(df)
            outputs
1 mpg = 20.090625  
2 cyl = 6.1875     
3 disp = 230.721875
4 hp = 146.6875    
5 drat = 3.5965625 
6 wt = 3.21725
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really starting with a matrix, it makes sense to use `colMeans()` or `apply()`.  For example:

```r
m <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
colnames(m) <- c("white", "black")

colMeans(m)
#> white black 
#>   1.5   3.5
apply(m, 2, mean)
#> white black 
#>   1.5   3.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This isn't such a good solution if `m` is really a dataframe, because it converts it to a matrix.  Then `sapply()` would be good, e.g.

```r
sapply(mtcars, mean)
#>        mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
#>  20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
#>         vs         am       gear       carb 
#>   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Both colMeans and as.matrix preserve names so this gives the output desired and will be more efficient and self-documenting that if one uses one of the *apply functions:

```
cars <- mtcars
cmeans <- colMeans(cars)
as.matrix(cmeans)
#------------
          [,1]
mpg   20.090625
cyl    6.187500
disp 230.721875
hp   146.687500
drat   3.596563
wt     3.217250
qsec  17.848750
vs     0.437500
am     0.406250
gear   3.687500
carb   2.812500
```

Furthermore you can index that structure with names:

```
> mat_as_col <- as.matrix(cmeans)
> mat_as_col[c("disp", "wt"), ]
     disp        wt 
230.72188   3.21725 
> mat_as_col[c("disp", "wt"), , drop=FALSE]
          [,1]
disp 230.72188
wt     3.21725
```